# wso2esb - redundant headers from HTTP request

Tags: rest, rabbitmq, wso2-esb

I have written a simple proxy in WSO2 ESB to just handle HTTP request and send message to RabbitMQ queue.
Here's my proxy service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy name="TestProxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="https http" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <target>
        <inSequence>
            <header action="remove" name="Accept" scope="transport"/>
            <property action="remove" name="SOAP_ACTION" scope="default"/>
            <property action="remove" name="SOAP_ACTION" scope="transport"/>
            <property action="remove" name="SOAP_ACTION" scope="axis2"/>
            <property action="remove" name="SOAPAction" scope="default"/>
            <property action="remove" name="SOAPAction" scope="transport"/>
            <property action="remove" name="SOAPAction" scope="axis2"/>
            <header action="remove" name="Action" scope="default"/>
            <header action="remove" name="Action" scope="transport"/>
            <property name="transport.jms.ContentTypeProperty" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="Content-Type2"/>
            <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
            <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" action="remove" scope="axis2"/>

            <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>

            <property name="CONTENT_TYPE" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
                        <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true" />

            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{"test": "test2"}</format>
                <args>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address trace="disable"
                        uri="rabbitmq:/TestProxy?rabbitmq.server.host.name=localhost&amp;rabbitmq.server.port=5672&amp;rabbitmq.server.user.name=test&amp;rabbitmq.server.password=test&amp;rabbitmq.queue.name=inputQueue_001&amp;rabbitmq.exchange.name=amq.direct&amp;rabbitmq.queue.routing.key=inputQueue_001&amp;rabbitmq.message.content.type=application/json"/>
                </endpoint>
            </send>

        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <header action="remove" name="Accept" scope="transport"/>
            <property action="remove" name="SOAP_ACTION" scope="default"/>
            <property action="remove" name="SOAP_ACTION" scope="transport"/>
            <property action="remove" name="SOAP_ACTION" scope="axis2"/>
            <property action="remove" name="SOAPAction" scope="default"/>
            <property action="remove" name="SOAPAction" scope="transport"/>
            <property action="remove" name="SOAPAction" scope="axis2"/>
            <header action="remove" name="Action" scope="default"/>
            <header action="remove" name="Action" scope="transport"/>
            <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" action="remove" scope="axis2"/>
            <send></send>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence/>
    </target>
</proxy>
```

From few days I am struggling with removing headers from message send to queue. 
Here's my message on inputQueue_001:

[image]

and I have no idea how to remove all headers...

Do you have any clues???

I will appreciate any help and examples.

Comment: I came across same problem could anyone is aware what is going on in wso2 esb 5.0+?

Comment: If you need to remove headers from the message sent to rabbitmq you need to remove them just before the send mediator in insequence

Comment: Could you give any example? I am newbie in WSO2 and I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All transport headers are saved in axis2 message context, in a property named TRANSPORT_HEADERS : delete it before send mediator

```
<property action="remove" name="TRANSPORT_HEADERS" scope="axis2"/>
```